# Understanding an easy combinatorial formula

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We know ${n \choose k}$ means the number of of size $k$ of a set of $n$ objects. Why is that? The argument is: First we pick the first element. We have $n$ choices to do that. Now, we pick the second member and we have $n-1$ choices and so on until we get to the $k$ member and to do this we get $n-(k-1)$. So,

$$ n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)$$

is the number of ways to pick $k$ members from a set of $n$ members. My question is: Why do we have to divide this by $k!$?? I am having a hard time understanding this concept.

Comment: Yeah, except you picked them ordered. Like, if I only care about what I picked, picking A, B, C is the same as B, A, C

Comment: Because the order you pick them in doesn't matter.  Picking A and then B gives the same result as picking B and then A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
6\times 5\times 4 = 120
$$
If the six objects are called $A,B,C,D,E,F,$ then the three chosen objects may be $A,D, F.$ There are three of those and we divide by $3!=3\times2\times 1 = 6.$ Here's why:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
1 & ADF \\ 2 & AFD \\ 3 & DAF \\ 4 & DFA \\ 5 & FAD \\ 6 & FDA
\end{array}
$$
That set of objects appears $6 = 3\times2\times1=3!$ times. But we want to count it only once, so we divide by $6.$